# Success in $.ajax is not get executed

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I am novice to ajax. As the first example, I wanted to implement an add operation. For the purpose, I wrote following code:

Html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Add two numbers</title>
    <meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
    <meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding">
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="addForm" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="first">
        <input type="text" name="second">
        <input type="submit" name="btnSubmit">
    </form>
    <script src="global.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

PHP:

```
<?php 
    header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
    $json  = array('success' => false, 
                    'result' => 1
                    );


    if (isset($_POST['first']) && isset($_POST['second']))
    {
        $json['success'] = "true";
        $first = $_POST['first'];
        $second = $_POST['second'];
        $json['result'] = $first + $second;
    }
    echo json_encode($json);
 ?>
```

global.js

```
$('#addForm').on('submit',
    function () {
        // alert("hello submit");

        var contents = $(this).serialize(); 

        $.ajax(
        {
            url:'add.php',
            dataType: 'json',
            type:'post',
            data:contents,
            success:function(data)
            {
                if(data.success)
                {
                    alert("result is " + data.result);
                }
            }
        }
            );
        // alert("Wfah");
    });
```

The problem is that when I uncomment the **// alert("Wfah");** , I get the result in ajax success and then redirect to add.php. When I don't uncomment it, I am directly redirected to add.php. It seems that success is not called.
Please help me. Also suggest be any good source to learn ajax. Thank You.

Comment: I believe , since ajax is asynchronous, your alert("Wfah"), gives you the necessary delay to be able to see your 'ajax success alert'. Which is why when it is commented out you do not see the 'ajax success alert' because the redirect to the php script has already taken place.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$('#addForm').on('submit',
    function (e) {
        e.preventDefault(); //<----- you need to prevent the form from submitting
        // alert("hello submit");

        var contents = $(this).serialize(); 

        $.ajax(
        {
            url:'add.php',
            dataType: 'json',
            type:'post',
            data:contents,
            success:function(data)
            {
                if(data.success)
                {
                    alert("result is " + data.result);
                }
            }
        }
            );
        // alert("Wfah");
    });
```

Comment: It worked. Can you explain a little bit? And also please tell me good source for jquery. I don't have 15 reputation, otherwise I would have upvoted..

Comment: events generally have a default action associated with it. e.g. above, the form has default action _submit_. when you use `preventDefault()`, you prevent the default action to be taken. for more info, [**click here**](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/)

Comment: @kmcnamee ? :P I could not get you? Ok got you . It is a good joke. Give and take.. I don't get upvotes on my questions generally.

Answer (score 1):

You are also setting `$json['success']` to the string `"true"` in your PHP snippet. This is probably just a minor logical error, but consider changing it to the boolean `true` literal:

```
$json['success'] = "true";
```

Into

```
$json['success'] = true;
```